# What do Swift underscore methods and functions do?

Tags: swift, built-in

While experimenting with Swift I found a lot of useful methods and functions that are prefixed with underscores. For example, strings have a hidden `_split()` method. For some reason the functions `_sin()` and `_cos()` (but not `_tan` or `_sqrt`) are also available by default. In fact, the REPL actually suggests me to use these functions when I type `sin(2.0)`. I’m not importing `Foundation` or anything that imports `Foundation`.

Why does the Swift offer these “hidden” functions, especially the trig functions which I would have expected to be part of a math module instead of builtins.

Comment: I *assume* that `_sin` and `_cos` refer to "LLVM intrinsic functions", see "UnaryIntrinsicFunctions " in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/BuiltinMath.swift.gyb and http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#intrinsic-functions. – `_split` is defined in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringLegacy.swift.

Comment: You'll get the full set of trigonometric functions with `import Darwin` on Apple platforms, `import Glibc` on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

> Things beginning with underscores are not for public consumption and only exposed publicly for internal reasons (e.g. for testing because the standard library can't use @testable).
>
> By [Dave Abrahams](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20161114/028911.html)

Comment: I can understand why there is `._split()` but now what exactly does the Swift standard library use sin(x) and cos(x) for anyway then?

Comment: That has been answered in the comments right below your main post. ;) Check the first GitHub link.

Comment: Could you add a link to the source of that quote?

Comment: @MartinR Done, he said that in a totally different topic, but the idea is the same. Underscore means hands off.